# Exploding string from a json

Tags: php, json, string, explode, implode

So, my problem is: I capture data from my database, part of this date is inside a json array. Then, I put all of the json information into an array. Like this:

```
foreach ($corporativos->lista as $value):
    $classe_row = '';

    $input = $value["info_adicionais"];
    $data = json_decode($input,true);
    echo $data['andamentos'];
    $arr1 = explode(',',$data['andamentos']);
  endforeach;
```

Now, I need to populate a table with this information. But I can't explode the string.

The strings are like this:

> " Name name name, 123123/uf; Name name, 123123/uf " and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First trim the string and explode on the ";" sign and on the "," sign as:

```
$str = " Name name name, 123123/uf; Name name, 123123/uf ";
$str = trim($str);
$temp = explode(";",$str);
if (count($temp) > 0) {
   foreach ($temp as $key=>$value) {
      $result[] = explode(",",$value);
      // OR
      $result[whatever the id you want here] = explode(",",$value);
   }
}
```